# Truncation of pointers when casting

Tags: c, pointers, casting, 32bit-64bit

I have the following situation:

- the function list_split returns a (list_t *)
- I call list_split and cast the return to (void **)
- The function returns 11054a2b8 but the var that receives the value gets 1054a2b8
- So, it seems that (list_t *) has 8 bytes but (void *) ha just 4 bytes

**Here is the code:**

```
typedef struct node_s *list_t;

typedef struct node_s {
  void *el;
  list_t tail;
} node_t;


list_t *list_split(list_t list, void **head)
{
  if ( list ) {
    *head = list->el;
    printf( " &list->tail = %p", &list->tail ));
    return &list->tail;
  }
  else {
    *head = (void *)NULL;
    return (list_t *)NULL;
  }
}

foo()
{
  void **list;

  list = (void **)list_split(*list, &ent);
  printf( "list = %p", list ) );
}
```

**And the Output:**

```
&list->tail = 11054a2b8
list = 1054a2b8
```

Comment: You have possible undefined behavior in your code: You call `list_split` with `*list` as first argument, but `list` is an uninitialized pointer (to pointer) so dereferenceing it will cause undefined behavior. I hope you're initializing it properly in your real code? Maybe you should edit your question to include a [short and self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) instead?

Comment: why don't you just print out sizeof(void*) and sizeof(list_t*) ?

Comment: If your void* is 4 bytes then your list_t* has to be of 4 bytes..

Answer (score 0):

It is totally unclear what this code does. Nevertheless it has undefined behaviour because variable `list` was not initialized in function `foo`but it (more precisely `*list`) is tested in function list_split

```
foo()
{
  void **list;  // What is the value of list?

  list = (void **)list_split(*list, &ent); // What is the value of *list?
  printf( "list = %p", list ) );
}


list_t *list_split(list_t list, void **head)
{
  if ( list ) {   // What is the value of list?
//...
```

And next time try to present a simple complete compiled example of code that everybody could test it.

Comment: list was initialized. The complete declaration was: void **list = &clients;. _clients_ points to a linked list. Sorry for the missing info.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

- *foo* and *list_split* are in different files (an info should had shared)
- there are no prototype for *list_split* in the file where *foo* was defined

The code worked fine in 32 bits. It was just when I recompile it to 64 bits that the problem showed up. I think it was because, with no prototype, the compiler assumes a 4 byte return.

Thanks for the anwers. I should share all the information but I did not thought it was relevant.